# Reflect and compare property value of complex type?

Tags: c#, reflection

The following function `AssignIfDiff`, which assigns the variable if it's different than the parameter, works well with simple type. However, it seems have problem with complex type? How to make it work on complex type?

```
class C 
{ 
     int A { get; set; } 
     List<AClass> B { get; set; }
     ...... 
}
C _c = new C(....); // To be updated

int v = 1;
AssignIfDiff(v, x => x.A); // Update _c.A if it's different than v. It works well.
var b = new List<AClass>(); .....
AssignIfDiff(b, x => x.B); // ???

void AssignIfDiff<T>(T curr, Expression<Func<C, T>> prev)
{
    var expr = (MemberExpression)prev.Body;
    var prop = (PropertyInfo)expr.Member;
    if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(curr, (T)_c[prop.Name]))
    {
        prop.SetValue(_c, curr, null); // Update the property of _c if diff than curr
          ...... 
    }
}
```

Comment: is AClass a random class ? also your function AssignIfDiff access _c somehow ?

Comment: Yes  AClass can be any random class. Right _c should be passed as a parameter. One major purpose of the function is updating _c.

Comment: I did not understand what _c is, it seems that C implements square brackets, is it some kind of container or dictionary ?

Comment: Why don't you compile and invoke the expression and use Object.Equals()? Or just `T prevObj = prev.Compile().Invoke(_c); if(prevObj != curr) { prop.SetValue(_c, curr, null); }`

Comment: When you say AssignIfDiff has a problem with a complex type, what is the problem exactly?  Could the problem be in the code for the equality check of AClass, such as an overridden Equals method is claiming all instances of AClass are equal to each other?